# Moving an object left and right on particular top scroll position jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, jquery-animate

I want to move an object having position `absolute` from left to right then right to left on particular scroll position. My object is at a particular position say from left it is `left:300px`. I want when top scroll reaches to `150px` or greater, the object moves to `100px` to right so that it left becomes `left:400px` and then it stops. Now matter how much we scroll down. And when user scroll top and again scroll top becomes `0`, the object again moves to left by `100px` and it left again becomes `left:300px;`

I have been trying `jQuery animate` and one [jQuery Transit plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/). When I use `jQuery animate` it starts moving to right and then not stop on scroll down and continue to move right. When I use transit plugin it moves to right by 100px then stop there. But in either condition it doesn't move to left to its original position when scroll reaches to 0. My code looks like

```
$(window).on('scroll',
        function() {
            windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (windowScrollTop == 0) {
                //using transit plugin. It should move to left by 100 px;
                $('.frameTwo .laptopClosed').transition({left: +100}, 1000, 'in');
                //$('.frameTwo .laptopClosed').animate({right: '+=100'}, 1000, 'linear');
            }
            if (windowScrollTop >= 150) {

                $('.frameTwo .laptopClosed').transition({x: 100}, 1000, 'in');
                //animate code commented
                $('.frameTwo .laptopClosed').stop().animate({left: '+=100'}, 1000, 'linear');
            }

        }
);
```

HTML

```
 <div class="laptopClosed">
    <img src="laptopclosed.png">
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.laptopClosed {
    left: -325px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 314px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-=100` when `srollTop=0` like,

```
if (windowScrollTop == 0) {
    //using transit plugin. It should move to left by 100 px;
    $('.frameTwo .laptopClosed').transition({left: '-=100'}, 1000, 'in');
    // ------------------------ Use negative sign --^ here 
}
```